# If within Repository implementations we only plan to use O/RMs, could we then use TransactionScope approach instead of IUnitOfWork?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, unit-of-work

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{        
    void Save();
}
```

Assuming we plan to only ever switch between different O/RMs ( access to these O/RMs is encapsulated using Repository pattern ), which already provide their own implementations of a Unit of Work pattern, are there any reasons why we shouldn't use `TransactionScope` approach instead of `IUnitOfWork`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of your IUnitOfWork can use whatever technological means of "transactionalizing" the changes between different aggregates at one time that you wish, be it TransactionScope, SqlTransaction, or whatever means you choose to use.  This does not negate the need for IUnitOfWork though.

Repositories are designed for a specific aggregate.  If you are only persisting changes to a single aggregate type at a time, then you may use only the repository.  But, if you are persisting different aggregates at the same time and need that persistence to be "transactionalized" so that the changes are persisted all or nothing, then this is where the Unit of Work pattern comes into play.

Per your example, we'll say you are using Linq as your OR/M and you're persisting your aggregates to a SQL data store, but want to wrap the persistence into a TransactionScope.  You may have an IUnitOfWork definition like so:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork 
{
  void MarkDirty(IAggregateRoot entity);
  void MarkNew(IAggregateRoot entity);
  void MarkDeleted(IAggregateRoot entity);
  void Commit();
  void Rollback();
}
```

Then, your implementation may be like this:

```
public LinqTransactionScopeUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public void Commit()
    {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            foreach (IAggregateRoot root in Changes)
            {
                //Save root based on how it was marked and what it's concrete type is using Linq.
            }

            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

The main idea here is that TransactionScope is one way of implementing IUnitOfWork, but having the Unit of Work contract allows you to provide different implementations based on your environment.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I assume it is not uncommon to use several different ( ie of different type ) IUnitOFWork implementations at the same time, where each implementation is used in different part of an application?

Comment: You may or may not have multiple impl. within the same project, but what if you port your core domain project to a different environment where TransactionScope isn't available such as making it a client app (where you can't count on DTC service running) or porting it to a mobile app?  Having the contract allows you to provide a different impl. based on the new environment without having to re-write your core domain project making your domain code more flexible and scalable.

Comment: In your opinion, should IUnitOfWork implementation reside within BLL or DAL layer?

Comment: Depends on the architecture, but assuming you're using Onion architecture or something similar where the domain (BLL) has no dependencies, the IUnitOfWork contract would reside in the domain (BLL).  Then, in your app infrastructure project, you would provide your implementation that matches the environment you are currently coding for.  This is also true for the repositories.

Answer (score 1):

There is one technical reason : you might have difficulties using TransactionScope in your environment, you need to start a service & unlock firewall port.
I you don't have these problems I'd suggest you to use TransactionScope : it's already done / debugged, why would you think you'd do something better ?

Comment: Just to be sure, are you suggesting I should use TransactionScope directly ( assuming I don't have problems with a firewall ), without first wrapping it within IUnitOfWork implementation?

Comment: yes, if you're doing a web app you can create it on your Application_BeginRequest and commit it on the endrequest. Why would you wrap something if you're not adding anything ?

Comment: "Why would you wrap something if you're not adding anything " You don't agree that arguments provided by Aaron Hawkins make for strong enough reason to wrap TransactionScope within IUnitOfWork?

Comment: I don't understand his point, how do you handle his solution when you need to insert your data then work with it ? (for instance you need it's id). you can't because your entities will get their id only when you commit your unit of work. That's the problem with over-encapsulating.

Comment: @remi bourgarel If I understand your situation correctly, the Unit of Work implementation would be responsible for saving the AR and getting and tracking the ID.  If you have this particular need, then the implementation of MarkDirty or MarkNew would do your preliminary save getting your id and saving it in memory until everything gets committed just as you would do if you were using TransactionScope by itself.

Comment: @Aaron, yes you can produce as much code as you want, but as I said, how would it be better than something already done and debugged that you can use at the infrastructure level (leaving your business code clear) ?

Comment: The question is tagged with domain driven design, therefore, I have to assume that he is looking for a solution that is in line with the benefits of designing a solution focused on the problem domain.  The Unit of Work pattern is meant to solve the problem of "How do I transactionalize changes to several entities at once?", which TransactionScope does handle by itself in an infrastructure specific way. Making it a contract allows you to solve the problem of keeping the domain model isolated which affords you the benefits of writing code that's focused on the problem domain.

Comment: if he really wants this to be explicit, then moves it from the infrastructure to the business code. But its rare that your client asks for transaction, he wants data to be clean so TransactionScope his a nice way to keep your data clean.